# Параметр не проходит проверку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Создал проверку, является ли параметр переменной типа int или float, но каждый раз условие заходит в else, хотя, если сделать `print(type(int(arg)))`, то будет выведено `<class 'int'>`. Почему так?

```
elif opt in ('-t', '-timeout'):
    int(arg)
    if isinstance(arg, int) and arg >= 1:
        timeout = arg
    elif isinstance(arg, float) and arg >= 1.00:
        timeout = arg
    else:
        print('Parameter [--timeout] must be an integer or float and not to be less than 1')
        sys.exit(2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так у вас во время проверки `arg` как являлся строкой, так скорее всего и является. Вот это строчка:

```
int(arg)
```

не влияет ни на что. Так как `arg` не модифицируется. Замените на

```
arg = int(arg)
```

Только `int` будет работать только для целых чисел, а для `float` выбрасывать исключение. Можно вместо этого использовать:

```
import ast
type(ast.literal_eval("23.33"))  # float
type(ast.literal_eval("23"))  # int
```